# I want to download file by passing its location_path to a function (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My View index.html.erb looks like this:

```
<p><% @filelist.each do |d|%>
    <p><%= link_to d, download_file(loc:"/lib/",file:"del.docx")%></p>
<% end%>
</p>
```

My Controller class

```
def index
    @filelist = Dir.entries(".").select {|f| !File.directory? f}
end

def download(loc,file)
    send_file path:loc, filename:file
end
```

But doesn't work. Can any one suggest any right way of doing this?

I want to pass the file location to the method and the method should return file at the location and user should be able to download it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "doesn't work"?

Comment: The intention of the code is to allow user to download the file without giving out any public URL as I want to track the downloads. Here this code doesn't work for downloading the file

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `index.html.erb`:

```
<p>
  <% @filelist.each do |d|%>
  <%= link_to "#{d}", '/lib/del.docx' %>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Hasmukh. But I don't want to give user a URL to file as I want to record 'who has downloaded what' in the calling method.